# Rotating Bone Rotates on all Axis

Tags: rigging

whenever I rotate my bone it micro rotates on the other axis as well. I recalculated roll - maybe I selected the wrong option. Trying to avoid having tons of extra keyframes.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

[image]